# Get or set the logback timestamp

Tags: java, logback

In order to be able to easily relate other program outputs to logs, I'd like to be able to get or set the exact timestamp logback uses.

I'm aware of `MDC` which I use to track the request and the logged-in user, but having the millisecond-precise timestamp would help even more.

Comment: You mean you want to set the timestamp in the call itself? What's the problem with using the MDC for that as well?

Comment: @Thomas Then I'd have two timestamps in such a call, which sounds pretty confusing. I could probably add some other information, like some exception ID, but reusing the timestamp looks better.

Comment: I'm not sure about the capabilities of logback but the frameworks I know would allow me to define a format that actually doesn't contain the actual timestamp but could get the timestamp from the MDC. You'd have to always provide the timestamp in that case though. - Taking a step back, is it really necessary to get the exact timestamp? Wouldn't the thread name etc. help as well?

Comment: @Thomas The problem with this is that I'd either have to change the format dynamically or always think about updating the MDC value so that I don't get stale values... this would work for my own logging well (as I could replace all usages by a trivial wrapper doing it), but it won't work for libraries. *Only strings are allowed in the MDC, otherwise I could put there my own object producing any string I want.*

Comment: Ok, what about taking the step back then? In what way would setting the exact millisecond make analyzing logs easier? What problems do you face?

Comment: I agree with @Thomas. This seems to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), i.e. you're down the wrong path for solving your problem.